# Center two elements side-by-side using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to use CSS flex to horizontally center an anchor and a paragraph next to each other on a page?

I'm trying to avoid using `float` on the anchor and paragraph though I've not exactly mastered flex.

The anchor/image should appear to the left of the paragraph though they as a whole should remain centered.

What I've got to thus far:

```css
section
{
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <a href="#">
  <img alt="Example" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
 </a>
 <p>Description goes here...</p>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eondkrpd/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="#">
    <img alt="Example" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <p>Description goes here...</p>
</section>
```

- `display: flex` creates the flex container
- `flex-direction: row`, a default setting (i.e., it can be omitted), makes the main axis horizontal, aligning the children (flex items) in this direction
- `justify-content: center` will center the flex items along the main axis

More details here: [*Methods for Aligning Flex Items*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)